# "This looks like spam" error message when attempting to ask a non-spam question

Tags: support, asking-questions, spam, spam-detection

I realize that similar questions have been asked, but through all of the ones I've seen, the answers seem to be specific, normally asking the author about the specific question.

I'm trying to ask in the "[Game Development Stack Exchange Q&A Site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)" about why video games are violent—is it a historical convention, a practical necessity, what people want? But when I try to post I get the "This looks like spam." error message and am not allowed to ask my question.

What can I do?

Comment: It would probably help if you editing this question and include verbatim what you were trying to post there so that maybe it'll be obvious to us what is problematic about what you were trying to post.

Comment: @n8te He might not be able to because of the very same error message.

Comment: Could be. But you don't think it'll let him if puts it all in quotes? I figured maybe it was a length issue or something similar.

Comment: Code format would be *much* better than putting it in quote format. Quote format can "adjust" what's displayed, whereas code format should show it verbatim.

Comment: If the system prevents you from putting it here, create a new paste on https://pastebin.com/ and link to it here.

Comment: @user134300 not one of them, but this does address one specific question, which implies one specific site. (In the past we used to close those as "Too Localized")

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Post a shorter question.

There are a whole pile of "trigger words" that will block a post based on their use in various spam campaigns. One word won't do it, but a high proportion of words will, as will a simple volume of trigger words.

You have almost 700 words in your question. And, you use the same words a lot: about 30 instances for both "game" and "violent" and variations for example.

Trim it down a bit. Also, read [what is on-topic for Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first. Try to find a clear, answerable question and include enough information about what you're doing to help us understand where you're coming from; dispense with broad commentary and irrelevant personal notes. Aim for 3-4 paragraphs, enough to fit comfortably on-screen and not so much that folks will give up; this isn't a discussion forum or debate society, and problem statements are generally very short.

Comment: You have access to the drafts, or did you see in the server log files?

Comment: There's a log generated for spam-blocked posts for precisely this reason, @Shadow

Comment: Huh, very neat.