# "This looks like spam" error message when attempting to ask a non-spam question on tor

Tags: support, asking-questions, spam, spam-detection

I'm trying to ask in the ["Tor Stack Exchange Q&A Site"](https://tor.stackexchange.com) about **Signaled readiness to systemd...** but always count my question as spam while it is not...

my question body : https://pastebin.com/tTEh3Szs

Comment: Spammers often leave email, so likely the email triggers the alert. Unless vital to the question, remove it.

Comment: @Joachim no offense to Adam but that is a pretty useless duplicate target.

Comment: @rene Yeah, but among all the similar questions this one at least makes an attempt to give an answer applicable to all situations. I don't think we need a question like this for every specific scenario and site. There is [this Q](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311147/) which is also used to link closed questions to, but it's even less useful (no offence to Shog9). And the proposed Q's answer also explains *why* the spam filter can't be more specific.

Comment: @Joachim well, we need a FAQ then where you can compile all answers I've written for these type of questions. I need the rep.

Comment: @rene I never intended to deny you that rep. The first thing I noticed was that you need the rep.

Answer (score 5):

Your body starts like this:

````
Hello everybody,
Tor isn't fully starting nor bootstrapping! due to **Signaled readiness to systemd...**
and connections keeps on throwing time-out errors...
 
**journalctl -xeu tor@default.service**:
```
May 13 20:34:56 ZDei systemd[29470]: tor@default.service: Executing: /usr/bin/tor --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/
````

Here are the things to try:

- We don't need opening statements. Remove `Hello everybody,`
- Don't do `**Signaled readiness to systemd**` inline. Instead make it a proper  quote by having it on a new line (empty line before it) that starts with a `>`  followed by a space and then a new blank line following it.
- Don't end a paragraph with multiple periods ...
- Headers are created with the hash character. Instead of `**journalctl -xeu tor@default.service**:` do `### journalctl -xeu tor@default.service` followed by a blank line.
- Code blocks should always start with a blank line before the code fence and end with a blank line after the last code fence.
- Spammers often leave email, so likely the email triggers the alert. Unless vital to the question, remove it.<sup>1</sup>

Generally: you have a lot of "code" / logfile with little other substance. Are you sure everyone needs all of that to diagnose your issue? Reducing the overall length of the post is advised when you run into the specific error you face.

If that doesn't solve the issue, copy everything out and add it back piece by piece, checking each time if you fulfill the quality requirements.

---

<sup>1. thanks to [Shadow The Spring Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859) for providing that tip</sup>